# After xcode 10 update, while first time load of Application Touch point is not correct

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

After xcode 10 update, while first time load of Application Touch point is not correct.

When i install the App, UI loads correctly but touch action place is changed to little up.
when I re-open the App, it loads everything perfectly.
Please suggest
Ionic 3
Angular 4
xcode 10

Comment: What's an "Application Touch Point?"

Comment: Let's say We have a tab bar at bottom, in UI it renders correctly, but when I try to click on it, it doesn't work, because the touch point for action of tab bar is replaced little up not sure how and why

Comment: I see. This could be more than likely a bug on Apple's end. Share your UI template and the functions that are trigger on a click event to identify if the issue is with your code.

Comment: Okay, but its working fine with Xcode 9 now with IOS 11, issue is only with Xcode 10 and ios 12

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue, it looks like it's related to the keyboard shifting the touch points up when the keyboard is displayed, but not shifting them back after it's dismissed:  https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/417

I ended up solving the problem by updating the wkwebview plugin and installing the new keyboard plugin (I was using a depreciated version, you might be too): cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard.

Make sure you uninstall the old keyboard plugin before adding the new one.